# how can I do calibration for 8-bit quantization using KL Divergence

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, quantization, tensorrt

I have FP32 tensor inputs which shape are [1, 4, 1024, 256]
I need to quantize the tensor to INT8, but naive quantization has triggered a problem in my NLP model that actually get rid of EOS.

So I have to do calibration rather than go with 'absolute min, max value'. And I have a problem with doing KLD calculation.

```
INPUT : A (tensor of FP32, [1, 4, 1024, 256])
A_int8 = A.clone().to(torch.int8).cpu()
P = norm.pdf(A)
Q = norm.pdf(A_int8)
P = torch.from_numpy(P)
Q = torch.from_numpy(Q)

kld = torch.nn.KLDivLoss(size_average=False)(A_int8, A)
print(kld)    

# After this, I'm going to apply self-attention operation.
# B_int8 = A_int8.clone()
# AB = A_int8.matmul(B_int8.transpose(-1, -2))
```

And I get the negative value for kld. Please help me with this.